# How to store a pointer in a custom embedded Python object

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, pointers

I have created a custom Python type in C as per the tutorial https://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/newtypes.html#the-basics. In my C I receive a pointer to a struct, I want to be able to get and set the values in the struct from Python without taking a copy of it. I.e.

```
a = myObject.x() # gets the x value in the struct.
```

or

```
myObject.x(255) # sets the x value in the struct.
```

However I cannot see how to store the pointer in the python object.

My current object definition is currently just the basic object implementation from the python website.

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    myStruct *s;
} KeyObject;

static PyTypeObject KeyType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    "ckb.Key",             /* tp_name */
    sizeof(KeyObject), /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                         /* tp_itemsize */
    0,                         /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                         /* tp_print */
    0,                         /* tp_getattr */
    0,                         /* tp_setattr */
    0,                         /* tp_compare */
    0,                         /* tp_repr */
    0,                         /* tp_as_number */
    0,                         /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                         /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                         /* tp_hash */
    0,                         /* tp_call */
    0,                         /* tp_str */
    0,                         /* tp_getattro */
    0,                         /* tp_setattro */
    0,                         /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,        /* tp_flags */
    "Key objects",           /* tp_doc */
};

static PyMethodDef key_methods[] = {
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};
```

Comment: It's hard to figure out from code fragments. What is `x` (from `myObject.x()`) - it looks like a method.  Also what is `myStruct *s`? It looks like you didn't read the _Python_ page til the end (yes it's very long). Please post full code, and explain where you have problems. Btw: did the _C_ module compile? If yes, is it importable in _Python_?

Comment: I was indeed going to implement `x` as a method of the object, doing that is not the issue I am having. Let's say the struct is
typedef struct {
        int x, y;
        unsigned char a, r, g, b;
    }

The object I have written does compile and I can create and interact with these object in Python. I know how to do methods for Python objects in C. The problem I am having is how to get that pointer into the KeyObject struct. I can't see how to get to this struct once I have made a KeyObject.

Comment: _Python_ doesn't know pointers. You should be able to access (r/w) the inner struct field from _Python_, but it would just be a number. I see here some over-nesting (if I got things right). One way to go would be moving `myStruct` fields directly in `KeyObject`.

Comment: Yeah I see what you are saying, I don't want to access the pointer from Python, hence why I am writing the wrapper object to perform all the pointer interaction in the C code. I cannot move the struct inside the object as its position in memory is important. I want to write a wrapper for manipulating these specific pieces of memory in Python as if they were objects.

Comment: So, to make sure that I understand: ftom _Python_: `myObject.x()` would call one of the `KeyType`'s methods (its name would have to be _x_) which would get `KeyObject->s.x`?

Comment: Yes indeed, well it would get `KeyObject->s->x` as s is also a pointer. And similarly when called with an argument this function will set the `KeyObject->s->x` converting from the Python value to a C value using the API functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example (*cbk.c*), that can act as a backbone for this task:

```c
#include "external.h"
#include "Python.h"

#define MOD_NAME "ckb"
#define KEY_CLASS_NAME "Key"


/*
typedef struct InnerStruct_tag {
    int x;
} InnerStruct;
//*/

typedef struct KeyObject_tag {
    PyObject_HEAD
    InnerStruct *inner;
} KeyObject;


static PyObject *Key_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds) {
    KeyObject *self;
    self = (KeyObject*)type->tp_alloc(type, 0);
    if (self != NULL) {
        //self->inner = (InnerStruct*)calloc(1, sizeof(Key));
        self->inner = getExternalPtr(1234);  // Don't allocate here, get the pointer from external lib
        if (self->inner == NULL) {
            Py_DECREF(self);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return (PyObject*)self;
}

static void Key_dealloc(KeyObject *self) {
    //free(self->inner);
    delExternalPtr(self->inner);  // Use the external dellocation function (optional)
    Py_TYPE(self)->tp_free((PyObject*)self);
}


static PyObject *Key_getX(KeyObject *self, void *closure) {
    return PyInt_FromLong(self->inner->x);
}

static int Key_setX(KeyObject *self, PyObject *value, void *closure) {
    if (value == NULL) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Cannot delete 'x'");
        return -1;
    }
    if (!PyInt_Check(value)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "'x' value must be an int");
        return -1;
    }
    self->inner->x = ((PyIntObject*)value)->ob_ival;
    return 0;
}

static PyGetSetDef Key_getsets[] = {
    {"x", (getter)Key_getX, (setter)Key_setX, "x", NULL},
    {NULL}  // Sentinel
};


static PyTypeObject Key_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    MOD_NAME"."KEY_CLASS_NAME, /* tp_name */
    sizeof(KeyObject),         /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                         /* tp_itemsize */
    (destructor)Key_dealloc,   /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                         /* tp_print */
    0,                         /* tp_getattr */
    0,                         /* tp_setattr */
    0,                         /* tp_compare */
    0,                         /* tp_repr */
    0,                         /* tp_as_number */
    0,                         /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                         /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                         /* tp_hash */
    0,                         /* tp_call */
    0,                         /* tp_str */
    0,                         /* tp_getattro */
    0,                         /* tp_setattro */
    0,                         /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT |
        Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE,   /* tp_flags */
    KEY_CLASS_NAME" objects",  /* tp_doc */
    0,                         /* tp_traverse */
    0,                         /* tp_clear */
    0,                         /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                         /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,                         /* tp_iter */
    0,                         /* tp_iternext */
    0,                         /* tp_methods */
    0,                         /* tp_members */
    Key_getsets,               /* tp_getset */
    0,                         /* tp_base */
    0,                         /* tp_dict */
    0,                         /* tp_descr_get */
    0,                         /* tp_descr_set */
    0,                         /* tp_dictoffset */
    0,                         /* tp_init */
    0,                         /* tp_alloc */
    Key_new,                   /* tp_new */
};

#define Key_CheckExact(op) ((op)->ob_type == &Key_Type)


static PyMethodDef module_methods[] = {
    {NULL}  // Sentinel
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initckb(void) {
    PyObject* m;
    if (PyType_Ready(&Key_Type) < 0)
        return;
    m = Py_InitModule3(MOD_NAME, module_methods,
        MOD_NAME": Example module that creates an extension type ("KEY_CLASS_NAME").");
    Py_INCREF(&Key_Type);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, KEY_CLASS_NAME, (PyObject*)&Key_Type);
}
```

**Notes**:

- Existing structure names / members was renamed (reorganized), for clarity
- The inner structure only has one member (*x*), which is enough for making a point
- Everything relies **solely** on the [[Python 2.7.Docs]: Defining New Types](https://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/newtypes.html#defining-new-types) page (that was mentioned in the question as well)
- Since the wrapper object (*Key*) contains pointers (*inner*), in order to avoid checking them for *NULL* every time they are accessed:

  - A constructor (*Key_new* - equivalent to *__new__* in *Python*) - that initializes them - was added
  - A destructor (*Key_dealloc* - equivalent *__del__* in *Python*) - that does the exact opposite - was added as well, to avoid memory leaks (this is just a previous bullet consequence)
- Access to *InnerStruct*'s *x* member is done via *Key_getX*, *Key_setX* functions (note they are referenced in *Key_getsets*):

  - From *Python*, the inner *x* member, will be accessed by *key_instance.x*, as it was a *Key* instance attribute

    - This way makes more sense than using a getter (*get_x()*) and a setter (*set_x(value)*), and is more *Python*ic
    - If however the getter / setter way is preferred, *Key_getX*, *Key_setX* signatures should be slightly modified (I think removing the last argument would do), and they should be referenced in *Key_methods* - that should be specified to *KeyType* as ***tp_methods*** (also described in the above web page)
  - When adding new members to *InnerStruct*, only the stuff done for *x* needs to be replicated and adapted (of course if there will be functions that look too similar, code should be refactored - but this is outside current scope)
- The last part is pretty standard *Python* extension module code

---

#### Update *#0*

After the 1<sup>st</sup> comment, it seems like the question is trickier than it seems. Not sure if I still get it wrong, because it doesn't seem such a big deal. The change is (as I understood), that the `inner` pointer should come from somewhere else (another library (*.dll*)), instead of being created in the constructor. Changed to the example to mimic the new (and hopefully expected) behavior:

- Since a *InnerStruct* pointer is returned by the external library (called it *external.dll*), the structure definition was moved in a header file belonging to that library - called it *external.h* (below), which is included by *cbk.c*
- Would make sense that a library exports some data via a function (also exported by the library): *getExternalPtr* which may take arguments - currently it only has (a dummy) one: *dummyArg0*
- Since *getExternalPtr* allocates memory inside, would make sense to have a corresponding function that deallocates it (*delExternalPtr*), in order to avoid memory leaks and *Undefined Behavior* (e.g. if memory is allocated in one place, deallocated in another, and the 2 places are deserved by different *C* runtimes). Any pointer returned by *getExternalPtr* should be passed to *delExternalPtr* **exactly once**
- The 2 above functions will now be called from *Key_new* and *Key_dealloc*. If this is still not *OK*, and the object needs to be modified **after** creation (although it may be possible that some race issues would arise), setting the member could be done like: `((KeyObject*)keyInstancePyObjectPtr)->inner = getExternalPtr(0);` with just **one catch**:

  - *keyInstancePyObjectPtr* (which is a generic *PyObject**) should be of type *Key_Type*. *Key_CheckExact* macro does exactly that check
- Now, the module depends (is *linked* to) on the *external* lib (not sure how things actually are), but that can be changed to *Dynamic (DLL (SO)) loading* (via [[Man7]: DLOPEN(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) / [[Man7]: DLSYM(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) or [[MSDN]: LoadLibrary function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)) / [[MSDN]: GetProcAddress function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx)

  *external* library code:

  - *external.h*:

    ```c
    #if defined (WIN32)
    #  if defined (EXTERNAL_DYNAMIC)
    #    if defined EXTERNAL_EXPORTS
    #      define EXTERNAL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    #    else
    #      define EXTERNAL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
    #    endif
    #  else
    #    define EXTERNAL_EXPORT
    #  endif
    #else
    #  define EXTERNAL_EXPORT
    #endif


    typedef struct InnerStruct_tag {
        int x;
    } InnerStruct;


    #if defined (__cplusplus)
    extern "C" {
    #endif

    EXTERNAL_EXPORT InnerStruct *getExternalPtr(int dummyArg0);
    EXTERNAL_EXPORT void delExternalPtr(InnerStruct *ptr);

    #if defined (__cplusplus)
    }
    #endif
    ```
  - *external.c*:

    ```c
    #include "external.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>


    InnerStruct *getExternalPtr(int dummyArg0) {
        InnerStruct *ret = (InnerStruct*)malloc(sizeof(InnerStruct));
        if (ret != NULL)
            ret->x = 1618;
        return ret;
    }

    void delExternalPtr(InnerStruct *ptr) {
        free(ptr);
    }
    ```

Test program (*ckb_test.py*):

```py
import traceback
import ckb

print "\nModule:", ckb
print "Dir:", dir(ckb)

print "\nClass:", ckb.Key
print "Dir:", dir(ckb.Key)

key = ckb.Key()
print "\nInstance:", key
print "Dir:", dir(key)

print "\nKey.x (initial):", key.x
key.x = 123
print "Key.x (modified):", key.x

try:
    key.x = 1.0
except:
    traceback.print_exc()

del(key)
print "\nEnd"
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> c:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q46833364>set PATH=%PATH%;.\external\Win32-Release
>
> c:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q46833364>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;.\ckb\Win32-Release
>
> c:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q46833364\>"c:\Install\x86\HPE\OPSWpython\2.7.10__00\python.exe" ckb_test.py
>
> Module: <module 'ckb' from 'c:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q46833364\ckb\Win32-Release\ckb.pyd'>
> Dir: ['Key', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
>
> Class: <type 'ckb.Key'>
> Dir: ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'x']
>
> Instance: <ckb.Key object at 0x027A7050>
> Dir: ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'x']
>
> Key.x (initial): 1618
> Key.x (modified): 123
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "..\ckb_test.py", line 20, in <module>
>     key.x = 1.0
> TypeError: 'x' value must be an int
>
> End
> ```

Comment: This is how much I had worked out for myself using the resource provided. I obviously haven't made myself clear. The problem I have is, the pointer to the struct is provided by an external library, and hence, can't be assigned in the Key_new function. I have an instance of a key object in C, which is of type `PyObject*` as this is what the C API uses to interact with python objects, my problem is how do I assign the `inner` variable from the outside once my object is constructed. This sort of C, Python interaction isn't documented on the tutorial page.

Comment: Then wouldn't casting the `PyObject` to `Key` and assigning the external structure pointer to `inner` member work? (e.g. `((Key*)keyInstancePyObject)->inner = externalInnerStructPointer`) work? Is it required to use that external pointer (or you can create another one and populate its member with values from the external one)? I'm afraid I'm still missing something, or it could be an _XY_ problem.

Comment: Aaaah yes, this is indeed what I needed. I didn't realise you can just cast the `PyObject` to a `Key` object like that.

Comment: In _C_ you can pretty much cast anything to anything (via pointers). The key is that the cast makes sense with respect to the referenced memory zone content. So when "downcasting" `PyObject*` to a specific type, make sure that the cast is OK, otherwise, the cast will succeed anyway, but after that you'll get _Undefined Behavior_.